# Matplotlib/basemap: plot a line with different colors, based on depending values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of lat/lon points, which represent the center of a hurricane, and a third list of wind speeds.  I'm trying to plot of the hurricane as a line connecting the lat/lons, but coloring the line various colors, depending on what the wind speed is at that location.

I've seen various threads on how to do this in matplotlib, but I'm having trouble making the conversion to basemap.

The following code is basic to plot the entire line in green, but as a rookie, I'm having trouble applying what I've seen regarding *segments* or a *listed colormap* work properly in the basemap forum. Probably because I'm misunderstanding how to link the wind values to the points. (I have yards of incorrect code trying these, so much so that I'll skip posting any because I confused myself).  Although I will post the listed colormap for reference.

I'm only going to be drawing 20-30 points here, tops, so timing and resources aren't an issue.

Am I way off base in attempting to apply either segments or a listed colormap? Appreciate any help!

```
map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=lowlat,urcrnrlat=highlat,llcrnrlon=leftlon,urcrnrlon=rightlon,lat_ts=30,resolution='i',area_thresh=10000)
map.drawmapboundary()
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.50)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
map.drawstates(linewidth=0.25)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,10),labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,10),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
plt.title(ensupper + ' Tropical Cyclone ' + storm +' ' + cyd + ' ' + cyc + 'UTC Cycle' )


lat = [33.7, 32.9, 32.1, 31.5, 31.0, 30.7, 30.5, 30.4, 30.0, 29.4, 29.6, 29.9, 29.7]
lon = [-27.1, -26.6, -26.6, -26.6, -26.9, -27.4, -28.0, -28.5, -28.9, -29.9, -30.9, -31.4, -32.3]
wind = [49, 44, 53, 60, 69, 77, 86, 85, 85, 74, 75, 62, 44]

x,y = map(lat,lon)
map.plot(x,y,color='green',linestyle='solid',linewidth=1, markersize=1)

cmap = ListedColormap(['black', 'saddlebrown', 'green', 'gold', 'darkorange', 'red', 'purple'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 33, 64, 83, 95, 113, 134, 300], cmap.N)
```

Comment: You cannot use `plot` when you want to use different colors. Instead you need a `LineCollection` as shown [in this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).

Comment: That was it. I was trying to plot the colormap/line collection, which obviously failed.  I've got it working now.  Thanks!